# Importing Illustrator file to Photoshop: cut lines between shapes are visible

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes

So I've created a vector logo in Illustrator

[image]

Now, if I drag this image into Photoshop, automatically, the edges of the design (where I've used the Patherfinder tool, Divide) can be seen;

[image]

How do I fix this or avoid this, when using the Divide tool in Illustrator?

Answer (score 7):

The quickest and easiest way to fix this in this case is as follows:

- Select all of the shapes that make up your logo
- Duplicate them as a unit (copy and paste in front for instance)
- Combine all of the components into one shape using Pathfinder, Unite
- Colour this combined shape the main flat red of your logo
- Send it to the back

Screenshots below show the results with and without the red shape at the back:

[image]

For future reference, it is better when building logos like this to start with a shape that makes up the overall form of the logo and then build other objects on top of that shape, rather than having lots of slices that 'kiss' up against each other.

Comment: Many thanks, Chris. I will definitely use this advice!

Answer (score 3):

Extend one of the shapes a bit across the cut so they dont overlap, and push it to the back. The design should not be affected by this.

For example

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Lucian, I appreciate your solucian (get it?).